# I am getting a parenthesis error in Pascal. What is wrong?

Tags: delphi, pascal

the following line

```
writeln('The decimal equivalent is ', BinToDec(dec));
```

is giving me the error

'(' expected but ')' found

what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: `Dec` is a special word in pascal. Pick a different name for your variable.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov `Dec` is not a special word in Pascal. `Dec` is just a predeclared procedure, which lives in `System` module.

Comment: I guess `dec` variable is not declared in the scope of the statement.

Comment: I would pick a different variable name to avoid confusion with the System function `Dec`. `DecimalValue` would be more descriptive (I know, it's more typing, too, but typing is what creates more readable variable names :)).

Comment: Pascal is generally not a case-sensitive language; attempting to declare a variable `dec` will probably confict with a function `Dec()`. Choose your variable names carefully.

Comment: @lurker  I'm using dec as a parameter in a function called bintodec, I tried to change it, but then I get another error saying "not enough actual prameters"

Comment: Why don't you show the complete context of your problem?

Comment: Changing the name of a variable should cause no problems if you change it everywhere it needs changing. You should have, `writeln('The decimal equivalent is ', BinToDec(DecimalValue));` and make sure other usages of `dec` in your function are changed to `DecimalValue`.

Comment: @TheOddOwl: How did you "try to change it"? Anyway, there is no conflict with `System.Dec` unless you actually have no variable `dec` in scope. If there is none, then the compiler assumes you mean `System.Dec`. So show more of your code, i.e. where you declare the variable (if you do). Variables must be declared before they can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you get this compiler error is because your line of code doesn't have access to any variable or constant called "dec". Any value you're expecting to pass into BinToDev here isn't available in that sense.

Because of this, Delphi interprets "dec" as the Dec() function from the System unit. This function takes an argument so the compiler requires the opening parenthesis "(" - hence the error.

Your line of code compiles for me if I have a "dec" variable defined somewhere. If I remove the variable, I get your error.

Answer (score 3):

`dec` is an intrinsic procedure that decrements an ordinal variable. The compiler  when it encounters `dec` expects the `(` opening parens symbol, as with any other procedure call. Hence the error.

I suspect that you imagine `dec` to be a variable but that's not the case. If that were so then the compiler would see that symbol rather than the intrinsic procedure. In any case you should use a different variable name to avoid confusion.